# Matlab: How can I use the a center mouse button click to record/log the data shown by a datacursor?

Tags: matlab

I am new to using Matlab and I have just made my first custom datacursor for a scatter graph I have plotted. This datacursor shows me the x position, y position and the location of that point within the original matrix (row). I want to be able to call the datacursormode and then have a callback within the datacursor, so that pressing the center mouse button on the point it will log the point data shown by the datatip/cursor into a matrix or array.

The idea is to be able to click on a point of interest,see the data tip info and then if the user wants they can click on the point with the middle mouse button to log the data tip information displayed, then move straight to the next point, without re-calling the datacursormode. This should then result in a cell array/matrix of all the point information selected.

I have tried disp(pos) but this displays every point clicked and I want to be able to click on the point and see the info before deciding whether to log it or not. I have tried ginput but calling it disables datacursormode. I think a callback within the custom datacursor function is needed, but I can never get them to work.

Please help.

Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: Don't have the time for a full answer, but have a look at `assignin`/`evalin`, or alternatively create a handle object that you pass as input with your custom datacursor.